# ¿Cómo permitir seleccionar máximo dos días dentro de un rango de fechas con datepicker de jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Tengo la siguiente vista:

```js
$('#inicial, #final').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
});

let $inicial = $('#inicial'),
  $final = $('#final');

$inicial.datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
}).on('change', function() {
  $final.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());
});

$final.datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
}).on('change', function() {
  $inicial.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<link srv="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link srv="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.css" / <div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label>FECHA INICIAL:</label>
  <input type="text" name="inicial" id="inicial" class="form-control" placeholder="aaaa-mm-dd">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label>FECHA FINAL:</label>
  <input type="text" name="final" id="final" class="form-control" placeholder="aaaa-mm-dd">
</div>
</div>
```

La idea es que el usuario seleccione un rango de fechas, pero sólo puede seleccionar máximo un rango de dos días; es decir, el campo input con id **final** puede contener la misma fecha que el campo **inicial** para establecer que sólo se está seleccionando un solo día o también **final** puede contener un día posterior a la fecha del campo **inicial** para establecer que se están seleccionando dos días.

Por el momento, lo único que he logrado establecer es que en el campo **final** no se puedan seleccionar fechas anteriores a la fecha seleccionada en el campo **inicial**. ¿Cómo podría lograr que también me bloquée las fechas que sobrepasen los dos días posteriores a la fecha seleccionada en el campo **inicial**? De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si usas `jquery ui datepicker` aqui te lo cuentan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827425/jquery-ui-datepicker-range

Comment: por mientras le puse a su código el bootstrap datepicker, pero creo que ese no es le que usa

Comment: @masterguru, sí estoy usando jQuery UI 1.8.16

Comment: y con que version de jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Capaz esto te puede ayudar.

Dejé deshabilitados los días de fin de semana, pero si deseas habilitarlos debes remover o comentar esta línea: `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],`.

Código JavaScript:

```
$("#inicial, #final").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6], // Deshabilita Sábado y Domingo
});

let $inicial = $("#inicial"),
  $final = $("#final");

$final.on("change", function () {
  
    //días que permitirá en el rango
    let limit = 2;

    //Identifico el día de la semana que se seleccionó en $inicial
  const selectedDay = new Date($inicial.val()).getDay();
  
  //Si el día fue jueves o viernes, el seteo rango a 4 días por los 2 de fin de semana
  if (selectedDay === 4 || selectedDay === 5) {
    limit = 4;
  }

  //Agrego los días de limit a la fecha seleccionada en $final para la comparación.
  const date = new Date($inicial.val());
  const dateLimit = date.setDate(date.getDate() + limit);

  //Si $final seleccionado es menor a $inicial o mayor a $inicial + limit, pongo fecha en blanco.
  if (
    new Date($final.val()) < new Date($inicial.val()) ||
    new Date($final.val()) > new Date(dateLimit)
  ) {
    $final.val("");
  }
});
```

Noté que estabas mezclando parámetros de Bootstrap datePicker con Jquery datePicker.